# Matlab fprintf in loop unexpected behaviour

Tags: matlab, for-loop, printf

I'm performing a calculation repeatedly with different values in nested for-loops with currently 7 levels. The results of my calculations shall be logged to a file. Therefore i'm using fprintf. Here is an extract of my code:

```
loadsignals;
fprintf('\n');
logfile = fopen(logfilename,'w');
if (logfile == -1)
    error('Couldn''t open logfile!');
end

%%% Initialisation of variables %%%
for thresalgi=1:length(arrthresalg)
for thressigi=1:length(arrthressig)
    for diffalgi=1:length(arrdiffalg)
        for detectsigi=1:length(arrdetectsig)
            for windowsizei=1:length(arrwindowsize)
                for windowshapei=1:length(arrwindowshape)
                    for Ki=1:length(arrK)
                        %% Prepare this round
                        thresalg  = arrthresalg{thresalgi};
                        thressig  = arrthressig{thressigi};
                        diffalg   = arrdiffalg{diffalgi};
                        detectsig = arrdetectsig{detectsigi};
                        K = arrK;
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'rectangle')
                            window = ones(1,arrwindowsize(windowsizei));
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'saw')
                            window = (1:arrwindowsize(windowsizei))/arrwindowsize(windowsizei);
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'sraw')
                            window = (arrwindowsize(windowsizei):-1:1)/arrwindowsize(windowsizei);
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'exponential')
                            window = flip(exp(1:arrwindowsize(windowsizei))/exp(arrwindowsize(windowsizei)));
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'rexponential')
                            window = exp(1:arrwindowsize(windowsizei))/exp(arrwindowsize(windowsizei));
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'root')
                            window = flip(sqrt((1:arrwindowsize(windowsizei))/arrwindowsize(windowsizei)));
                        end
                        if strcmpi(arrwindowshape{windowshapei},'rroot')
                            window = sqrt((1:arrwindowsize(windowsizei))/arrwindowsize(windowsizei));
                        end
                        %% Detect events
                        detectEvents; % Remark: the variables top of this statement are changed in this script, may this cause issues?
                        %% Evaluate result
                        [fp,fn,tp,tn] = compareResults(solevts,y,tolerance);
                        results{thresalgi,thressigi,diffalgi,detectsigi,windowsizei,windowshapei,Ki} = {fp, fn, tp, fn};
                        fprintf(logfile,sprintf('Thresalg: %s Thressig: %s Diffalg: %s Detectsig: %s Winsize: %d Winshape: %s K: %f done.\n     FP: %d FN: %d TP: %d TN: %d\n', thresalg, thressig, func2str(diffalg), detectsig, arrwindowsize(windowsizei), arrwindowshape{windowshapei}, K,int32(fp),int32(fn),int32(tp),int32(tn)));
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

When i let this run and open the generated file i get a proper result for the first line of the first iteration, but already the 2nd line and all following are weird:

```
Thresalg: meanval Thressig: d Diffalg: @(x)fwpdiff(x) Detectsig: s Winsize: 2 Winshape: rectangle K: 0.100000 done.
     FP: 1.246905e-01 FN: 1.554772e-01 TP: 1.938653e-01 TN: 2.417315e-01
Thresalg: 3.014163e-01 Thressig: 3.758374e-01 Diffalg: 4.686335e-01 Detectsig: 5.843414e-01 Winsize: 7.286182e-01 Winshape: 9.085176e-01 K: 1.132835 done.
     FP: 1.412538e+00 FN: 1.761300e+00 TP: 2.196174e+00 TN: 2.738420e+00
```

For me it seems like there are only pointers passed to fprintf that are not valid any longer when the data is written to the buffer. Is that possible?

I tried to find a simpler example to reproduce this issue, but wasn't able to create one.

Did anyone already occur something similar? Or is there a (trivial) error in my code?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you put a [breakpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) in at your `fprintf` line to see if your variables are being calculated correctly after the first iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the problem as to do with the variable `K`?   The innermost `for` loop is

```
for Ki=1:length(arrK)
```

and later, within the body of this loop, we set

```
K = arrK;
```

So now a local variable is set to the array which may have one or more numbers.  The `fprintf` is

```
fprintf(logfile,sprintf('Thresalg: %s Thressig: %s Diffalg: %s Detectsig: %s Winsize: %d 
    Winshape: %s K: %f done.\n     FP: %d FN: %d TP: %d TN: %d\n', thresalg, thressig, 
    func2str(diffalg), detectsig, arrwindowsize(windowsizei), 
    arrwindowshape{windowshapei}, K,int32(fp),int32(fn),int32(tp),int32(tn)));
```

Note that `K` is being written to the string as a float at the end of the first line.  If `K` is an array, this could explain why `FP`, `FN`, `TP` and `TN` are being written as floats and not as integers (as per the `%d`).  I think that rather than `K` the code should be writing out `Ki` as an integer.

Try making that change and see what happens!

Note also that you don't need to use `sprintf` to create the string that is passed to `fprintf`.  You can instead just have

```
fprintf(logfile,'Thresalg: %s Thressig: %s Diffalg: %s Detectsig: %s Winsize: %d 
    Winshape: %s K: %f done.\n     FP: %d FN: %d TP: %d TN: %d\n', thresalg, thressig, 
    func2str(diffalg), detectsig, arrwindowsize(windowsizei), 
    arrwindowshape{windowshapei}, K,int32(fp),int32(fn),int32(tp),int32(tn));
```

as `fprintf` takes the same inputs as `sprintf` (the format string and the variable list of arguments) after the file identifier (`logfile`).